# Big coefficient difference between logit/probit and linear probability model

Tags: logistic, linear-model, regression-coefficients

Setting: Large N, short T panel dataset. Very few 1's (probably 1 percent), most zeroes. I estimate a logistic regression and find a negative significant coefficient on the IV of interest. Reassuringly, it's negatively correlated with the indicator variable.

But when I run this in a LPM (with OLS), I find a positive significant coefficient.

What's driving this? Which (the negative or positive) is more likely correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Using weights with OLS? Heteroskedasticity could well be an issue.

Comment: What is an "LPM"?  Please spell out your acronyms and abbreviations so that all readers will share a common understanding of what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

That should not happen. Two possibilities I can think off are maybe you have outliers, or maybe you have perfect prediction that messed up your logistic regression estimates. Since the LPM is just a linear model you can use all the diagnostics developed for that. I would use those to try to find influential observations. Perfect prediction is handeled differently in different software packages. In Stata you would get a warning, but it would still give you (problematic) estimates.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. Some of my observations from my logistic model were "perfectly predicted" per Stata's output. I tried removing observations that were outliers (using Cooks' D and studentized residuals), but the observations that were removed were all the 1's, which means no logit regression! However, if I eliminate observations with a predicted probability below 0.001 (which is approximately 75% of the sample), I then get consistent results between the logit and LPM (in that I get a negative coefficient). Since I can't eliminate outliers that are 1s (or can I) would you advocate this approach?

Comment: I also found this link, of which my case is case #1, in case I wasn't clear above. http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/completely-determined-in-logistic-regression/

Comment: I wanted to add that I found one more link that suggests LPM could result in biased coefficients. A majority of my fitted values do lie outside the unit interval, and thus maybe the OLS results are biased (and logit is correct)? http://davegiles.blogspot.com/2012/06/another-gripe-about-linear-probability.html

Comment: The fact that most of your predicted values are outside the 0-1 range suggest a simple model misspecification, which is something different then the bias reported in that blog post. It does mean that your LPM model is problematic, but for a different reason.

Comment: I would not recommend removing outliers. Instead I would figure out why they exist and model them "appropriately". What "appropriate" means depends on the context.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses Maarten. I am modeling company failures, so I'll have to think carefully about what alternative models I might employ. I did want to report back that when I employ the advice of the Horrace and Oaxaca paper (and trim predicted values that came out of the LPM that were outside the united interval), the LPM result eventually converges to the logit result (of a negative coefficient), consistent (but not proof) of the suggestion of bias. In the meantime, knowing very little about my data/project, does it seem appropriate to continue with my logit regression for now?

Comment: I really don't know. At least you now know that your LPM is severly misspecified and that your logit model suffers from perfect predictions. I would start reading into what perferct prediction does, alternative ways of dealing with that, etc.

Comment: Actually, after reading this link, I'm not sure that I am suffering from perfect predictions. My Stata regression works fine, and at the end just says that some of my zeroes were completely determined (meaning I think that their predicted probability was essentially zero). Is that the same thing as perfect predictions? I'm not getting any messages that a variable perfectly predicts a value. http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/complete_separation_logit_models.htm

Comment: This is a point where I would start looking for books instead of web-pages. The internet is great, but you now need a longer text to study with much more detail.